# CreateDataPartition unable to execute function. error unexpected symbol in createDatapartition

Tags: r

```
quizR<-read.csv(file="seaflow_21min.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
createDatapartition(y=quizR$RT...index,times=2,p=0.5,list=FALSE)
```

it is returning the error as mentioned at the last  RT value is set at 1 index `[1] 1 2 3 4` ( index is set from 1 to 4 as there are 4 columns in the matrix quizR.

```
createDatapartition(y=quizR$RT...index,times=2,p=0.5,list=FALSE)
```

I receive error `"unexpected symbol in createDataPartition(y=quiz$RT ...index"`

Could you suggest what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: One of the incorrect things is failing to name the package from which this function is pulled.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're doing the Introduction to Data Science class too :)

My code for this part is:

```
library(caret)
data <- read.csv(file="seaflow_21min.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$cell_id+data$file_id, p=.5, list=FALSE, times=2)
```

Note: The `data$cell_id+data$file_id` is here because of the instructions that the key of the data is (file_id, cell_id). This is actually the first time I've seen/used R, so I just assumed that I should use + to combine these 2 columns and it seems to work (I get correct result).